# can PostgreSQL function talk to SQL Server 2000 as a linked server

Tags: oledb, remote-server, postgresql-9.2, heterogeneous-services

Situation: gradually migrating a boatload of legacy SQL Server apps to PostgreSQL.
Question:  can a PostgreSQL function execute a query against SQL Server 2000 database? Anything comparable to *[OpenQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b805e976-f025-4be1-bcb0-3a57b0c57717)*  in PostgreSQL? Or like Oracle's [Heterogeneous Services](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67784/hs_ch6.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

You can you DBLink between PostgreSQL instances.  There is a project out there for doing this to MSSQL call [dblink-tds](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dblink-tds/).  I have never used it, so I can't say how well it works. And it looks pretty old, so I'm suspicious it may no longer be supported.

But, remember with PostgreSQL you get your choice of languages to use.  if you need to access data in other non-postgresql stores, you can use one of the "un-managed" languages.  For example, plpythonu or you can always write your functions in C and access any information you need/want.